# How to scan older dot matrix QR codes?

Tags: android, qr-code, datamatrix

We use mobile vision sdk for scanning QR codes. Some older dot matrix codes scan with a time delay, and some don't scan at all.

We tried zxing sdk. Though scanned with a delay, it gave wrong results (1 was the result).

We tried zxing app also, but the codes were scanned with a wrong translation.

[image]

The code looks like below:

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void createCameraSource(boolean autoFocus, boolean useFlash) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        // A barcode detector is created to track barcodes.  An associated multi-processor instance
        // is set to receive the barcode detection results, track the barcodes, and maintain
        // graphics for each barcode on screen.  The factory is used by the multi-processor to
        // create a separate tracker instance for each barcode.
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
       /* BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(mGraphicOverlay);
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
                new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());*/

        if (!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
            // Note: The first time that an app using the barcode or face API is installed on a
            // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
            // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
            // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any barcodes
            // and/or faces.
            //
            // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
            // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
            // downloads complete on device.
            Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");

            // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
            // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
            IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
            boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

            if (hasLowStorage) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
            }
        }

        // Creates and starts the camera.  Note that this uses a higher resolution in comparison
        // to other detection examples to enable the barcode detector to detect small barcodes
        // at long distances.
        CameraSource.Builder builder = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), barcodeDetector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(15.0f);

        // make sure that auto focus is an available option
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            builder = builder.setFocusMode(
                    autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);
        }

        mCameraSource = builder
                .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up integrating ZXing library which worked for all types of codes